# Deleting version of a content in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I need to delete a specific version of content in Ektron.Is it possible to delete a version of content in ektron.I can view and restore it,but didnt find an option to delete it.

Anyone please reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a specific version from inside the ektron workarea.